# Need help with these polynomials

Tags: functions, polynomials

Three polynomials ,  and  are defined as follows:

$$: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, () = 8^{2} − 2 − 1,$$
$$: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, () = 2^{3} + 3^{2} − 2 − 3,$$
$$: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, () = ^{4} − 2^{3} + 2^{2} − 2 + 1$$

a) Determine the zeros of the polynomial and the multiplicity of these zeros.

b) Represent the polynomial as a product of real factors.

The zeros of a polynomial are the solutions to the equation e() = 0. To find the zeros of the polynomial $() = 8^{2} − 2 − 1$, set () = 0 and solve for . This gives the equation $8^{2} − 2 − 1 = 0$.

Not sure about ”the multiplicity".

How do I solve the questions without a graph calculator and by completing the square?

Comment: The multiplicity is the number of times each zero occurs.  For instance, if $f(x) = (x - 3)^2(x - 2)$, then the root $x = 3$ has multiplicity $2$ and the root $x = 2$ has multiplicity $1$.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Solving for x:
$$p(x)=8x^2-2x-1=0, p(x)=8x^2-4x+2x-1=4x(2x-1)+(2x-1)=(2x-1)(4x+1),  x=\frac{1}{2},\frac{-1}{4}$$are zeroes of p(x) each with multiplicity 1.
$$q(x)=2x^3+3x^2-2x-3=2x^3-2x+3x^2-3=2x(x^2-1)+3(x^2-1)=(x^2-1)(2x+3), x=+1,-1,\frac{-3}{2}$$are zeroes of q(x) each with multiplicity 1.
$$r(x)=x^4-2x^3+2x^2-2x+1=(x^4-2x^3+x^2)+(x^2-2x+1)=x^2(x^2-2x+1)+(x^2-2x+1)=(x^2+1)(x-1)^2, x=1 $$is the only zero as $x \in R$ with multiplicity 2.

Answer (score 0):

The multiplicity simply refers to the number of times each zero is a solution to the equation. For instance, $(x-1)^3=0$ has a zero $x=1$ with multiplicity $3$.

As for representing a polynomial as a product of real factors, think about the following:

If $p(x)$ is a polynomial with n solutions $a_n$, you can write it as:

$$p(x)=\Pi_{i=1}^{n}(x-a_i) $$

Comment: $1$ is a root of multiplicity 1 of $x^3-1$...

Comment: @Desperado Whoops, yeah... correcting it now.